# fabric js linking items with arrow

Tags: fabricjs

I need to use arrows to link item in Fabricjs the arrow normally should be linked to the two items even if we move one item or another.

home my question was clear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check [this](http://fabricjs.com/stickman)

Comment: If you want all of the objects to move together (or if you want an example of how to draw the arrow) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089356/arrow-is-not-drawn-correctly-on-fabricjs-canvas/40118389#40118389.

Comment: That awesome many many thanks... need just another point which is by this arrow I need to link a shape with another shape for example like linking a square with a square shouting the process of something... hope you got me. Thanks